# During the installation of CLHEP, I got an error like : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: makefile

I got an error when I installed CLHEP and typed 'make' like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CLHEP::HepVector::num_row() const", referenced from:
      CLHEP::HepRandomVector::operator()() in RandomVector.cc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libCLHEP-RandomObjects-2.1.4.1.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [RandomObjects/src/CMakeFiles/RandomObjects.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 99%] Building CXX object RandomObjects/src/CMakeFiles/RandomObjectsS.dir/RandomVector.cc.o
[ 99%] Built target ExceptionsS
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libCLHEP-RandomObjects-2.1.4.1.a
[ 99%] Built target RandomObjectsS
Linking CXX executable testInstanceRestore
[ 99%] Built target testInstanceRestore
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution posted [here](https://its.cern.ch/jira/browse/CLHEP-103)

```
--- CLHEP/Matrix/src/Vector.cc.orig 2014-04-01 09:21:25.000000000 +0200

+++ CLHEP/Matrix/src/Vector.cc      2014-04-01 09:22:17.000000000 +0200

@@ -114,9 +114,9 @@



 // trivial methods



-inline int HepVector::num_row() const {return nrow;} 

-inline int HepVector::num_size() const {return nrow;} 

-inline int HepVector::num_col() const { return 1; }

+int HepVector::num_row() const {return nrow;} 

+int HepVector::num_size() const {return nrow;} 

+int HepVector::num_col() const { return 1; }
```